# Make function param accepts only keys from variable object

Tags: typescript

I have an object with defined type for value:

```js
type Type = { [key: string]: ValueType }

const variable: Type = {
    key1: valueType,
    key2: valueType,
    key3: valueType,
}
```

And I have a function `func`, which I want to be accepting only string with values from `variable`'s keys:

```js
func('key1')     // OK
func('key2')     // OK
func('key3')     // OK
func('keyother') // Error
func(3)          // Error
```

And this is what I have done when making type for `func`:

```js
type FuncType = (param: keyof typeof variable) => any
const func: FuncType = ...
```

But I can only achieve one:

- typing for `variable`'s value

or

- typing for `func`'s `param` accept only `variable`'s key

Not both.

- If I'm typing for `variable`'s value `const variable: Type = {`, `param` has `string` type and I can pass any string to `func` call, which is wrong
- If I'm not typing for `variable`'s value `const variable: Type = {`, `func` now typing `param` correctly but it makes `variable` accept anything as value.

Another way I can think about is predefined `Type` with list of keys (`[key1, key2, ...]`). But I don't want to maintain two list of the same thing. How can I achieve both of them without doing this way.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgYUWANhAHgEQIbB4Aq40AvFAHYCuCARhAE4BQokUJ7FA3lANoBrCCABcUAM7BGAS0oBzALpj4SVAgzZ8hTtAC+zZgGM4lSVABueGXjqYxOqDygB6Z7EiHpAM2mGobaAALJggAGgk4CytpG0wAcnEo9GoIRIB3aXR0KAYoLzhGQ2g2WTlwumpgKEM8anFSvOpKPzxDIrAqvEoQYECGvETZMErmKDGoIRAARjEABlDR8cmAJjmF8YnhAGYxOLTGEzl-UiSUuPDXDmDGaGlEpgPGcLS+w0CoO+qCm8Mql4IoABJKBpLrAZj6VgnABiTUMAEE2hAOgAFKx4BDQg4IeF0ODmCAANWisQgAGlhI4oAAKMDohBiSZwLzHSDMqLWWwQACUjgAfFAuiADMZTFUvHCxLDmoj2sA0YwMVjELj8USSVyKSAqdTeWQBdxIRLmtS4pMpnFucxjYZTStLda4Xbtg6bc6QF48OhxBBLS43AA5SIPArhcSRXqfT6UOB-QIA4Ggyjgt1bXmXINQENPCL+PqDRIxuMJkFggyuAC0VerNdrdfrDcbTebLdbDYMAVgiBQaEwuAIxFIyypNHoTCh7B0w6cgmEYkkMnkSi7ql7mgHU6gkNFZksnMw06gvFcGV6cEqEg83hADSn4Rtw4yWSocDSUBM6G1rTlec+e5iXLLAkmwgOUF6Rok-6ksBljJNA37Ip03SRvIixjOaaxoSBqxQPMWGTDsUB7Ac8istAsFnBcgbBowjxhhG+YfIWsYgvGVSJmWkKdtKCJIqi9LKjieIEsS+7ksIh60vSjLCOyATslBgF6gKQoiiYZgPlKcKyohCpKtiqoiRqmBapJylHkacLLO6FpWg+7pAXZVnulsrrOWawiet6vrpm4RDXLc9y0aGrG+O8nzGLREC-KxJZJimzlpv6VwhExWbBTmLxhWlkU-MW7GlsmzBAA) for this problem, which has some comments to describe problem more clearfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use helper function that does nothing just validates type.

```js
const makeType = <T extends Type = Type>(obj: T) => obj

const variable = makeType({
    key1: 0,
    key2: 0,
    key3: 0,
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=56&pln=4&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgYUWANhAHgEQIbB4Aq40AvFAHYCuCARhAE4BQokUJ7FA3lANoBrCCABcUAM7BGAS0oBzALpj4SVAgzZ8hTtAC%20zZgGM4lSVAR4hOqBQA8RKNmARKAE3EdSNz5AB8ACjg6ACsxIgBKG18oIOCDY1NgKAA3PBk8OkxvCytSf25mKCKoIRAARjEABgAaQuLSgCYq2uKS4QBmZuZdcIM2aAAxakpDAEFDQwgwYAAFNLwEAcZEUbo4ZIgANTTpDMwAaWFvW33HLGc3D1K4ADMoftuUnb2IALB5hDF9yLJovEoQPETGYbsNDGIhiNxpNpnNGAslis1httulMhBDiBvP4ftFuPpmKCRv4AOSlMok3pEwykxqUwlg2kdenUpkgG54dDiCAsxntXrMAD0goAtGLxRLJVLpTLZXL5QrFTK%20l4VCg0JhcARiKQGt4aPQmKwvDo9Tx%20KUxJIZPIlLBEOr1JqtDrIHqCQkzKk0ZgzVACq1yV1A8ImlAanUiqVOuHagT%20lBIWMJlNZh9EQhVusts90Zi-Sczhd3G0QI8Hndvbt0Q03h8vrioP9AUZgUlqWGk9DU3CEctM8icz6MaHsY38QYO2yKVSwQ02Q1eSN52TmbPl2yOVyeevDPP%20cwgA)

### UPDATE: TypeScript 4.9 will make this possible with `satisfies`

[Announcing TypeScript 4.9 Beta](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/)

```
const variable = {
    key1: valueType,
    key2: valueType,
    key3: valueType,
} satisfies Record<string, ValueType>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you really mean there is no solution with only Typescript things, the only way is we have to add an empty js function like this?

Comment: Yes, right now Typescript doesn't support anything to define only value. You can only define whole object as a const or use this method.

Comment: Update: `satisfies` does satisfies what I want, make code very clean.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider BorisTB's solution quite good, since it's intuitive and straightforward, and to the best of my understanding fulfills the requirements you've set in your question.

When you say the solution didn't work, I presume you mean
"While both problems are detected if they are individually occurring (invalid key value in `variable`, invalid keyname in `func`), if they occur together you don't get errors for both at the same time".
If that's the problem, here is a slightly different solution:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=18&pln=4&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgYUWANhAHgEQIbB4Aq40AvFAHYCuCARhAE4BQokUJ7FA3lANoBrCCABcUAM7BGAS0oBzALpj4SVAgzZ8hTtAC+zZgGM4lSVABueGXjqYoPKAHpHsSIekAzaYahtoACyYIABoJOAsraRtMAHJxCPRqCHiAd2l0dCgGKA84RkNoNlk5ULpqYChDPGpxYpzqSh88QwKwCrxKEGB-Orx42TBy5igRqCEQAEYxAAZg4dHxgCYZudGx4QBmMRiUxhM5X1IEpJjQ5w5AxmhpeKY9xlCUnsN-KBvKvKvDCqeCKABJKApDrAZi6KB9D6mYAAbmYlmstmgkJ0cNYRwAYg1DABBFoQNoABSseAQGL2CBxdDg5ggADVItEIABpYT2KAACjAJIQYnGcA8h0gAoiiMwAEp7AA+CGdAzGaH1RpiLGNPGtYDExik8mIKk0+mMpGskDsjmSsgy7j6ZgebEcmLjCYxcW2+2O4SLF1uxoO8Ybb1230ekAePDocQQF1OFwAOXCdzyoXE4W673elDgP38f0BwMooKDhg5G0l53jUETDzCvh6-XimezuaBIOYQA)

The way it basically works is to do an additional check on variable after it is declared with it's const type.

```js
const variable = { 
    key1: 0,
    key2: 0,
    key3: 'wrong type value',
} as const;
variable as Type;
```

This additional check compiles to just `variable` on it's own, so it's not too disruptive either. You do get the same level of detail in the error as you would expect with just typing `variable` as `Type`, just with the added benefit of preserving the const type of `variable`.
If both invalid value in `variable` or a invalid argument to `func` is used, you get errors for both.

Comment: Thanks for providing solution. I had a miscommunication with BorisTB's solution. About you solution, it worked great but I wonder if anyone setup code like this, declare variable first and check typing later? In another hand, your solution does not provide as details as specific type at variable declaration `const variable: Type = {`. In above small example, it's not so different but it will when object has very many field, e.g: [playground](tinyurl.com/ts-play-1) (I cant format the link, can anyone help?)

Comment: In the playground example you show the error includes : `Property 'key72' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'string' is not comparable to type 'number'.` Which I'd say is all the detail that you usually get, and need. And yes, typechecking after declaration is very non standard. I just wanted to present an alternative solution.